# Program not showing result when result is more than 100?

Tags: c++

So I wrote a program that calculates the sum of every fifth integer, beginning with X (that the user will input) for all values less than 100.
I input numbers between 95-99 and it's fine, the result displays. But when I input 94, which adds 99 as it's less than 100, making the result more than 100 the result doesn't show and the program just stops there.
Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>


int main(){
clrscr();
int x,result=0;

cout <<"Enter a number below 100\n";
cin >>x;

for(int a=x;a<100;a=x+5){
    result=result+a;
}

cout<<"\n Result="<<result;

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can successfully include `iostream.h` your compiler is ancient. Upgrade as soon as possible, because you'll find it very difficult to write idiomatic C++ with it.

Comment: Also, this code is not portable and will only work on Windows.

Comment: Also, `<conio.h>` is not a standard C++ header. On Linux and MacOSX system, it does not exist. And please switch to at least a C++11 compliant compiler (where `<iostream.h>` does not exist)

Comment: Not to forget that the calls to `clrscr()` and `getch()` *also* betray a fundamental misunderstanding of how command-line programs are supposed to be used. In a command-line program, you generally only want to read from and write to stdin/stdout, using `std::cout` and `std::cin`, and not try to manipulate input or output in any other way. The program may not even run in a command-line window; consider `program.exe >file.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an infinite loop if you enter a number less than 95 because you never update x. What you meant to do was `a += 5`. Instead, after every time the loop does one iteration it will update `a` to be 5 greater than `x`, but since `x` is always the value the user inputted you never make any progress.

Comment: If the user enters a value of x of 95 or more (but less than 100 — so 95, 96, 97, 98, or 99), then the loop terminates after one iteration, does it not?  If `x` is larger than 99, then the loop executes zero times.  And users, of course, routinely ignore instructions like 'less than 100' (and choose values like `-100` as being 'less than 100')...

Comment: Happens all the time! Next time try stepping through your code with a debugger and examining the value of `a` after each iteration.